# Access of Cookies on server side

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I am designing a web application front end I am making use of HTML and at back-end I am using a servlet.At front end side I am storing some values in cookies that are to be used on the server side (i.e in servlet)

Now my question is :  How do I get the values of cookies in servlets.

Please help me with this.

Comment: I don't know how to use servelets but cookie data is passed in the header of every http request/response.

Comment: post **some** relevant bits of your code. Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpServletRequest has method getCookies(), it will return you array of cookies, so just look for your cookie. I assume you already know how to set cookie using servelt response.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are sent with every request to the web app, and should thus be used very rarely. You should probably use request (get/post) parameters, and store values that must persist for a whole user session in the HttpSession object.

Now, to answer your specific question: everything coming from the client browser is stored in the HttpServletRequest object. Browse [the javadoc for this class](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) (part of the Java Enterprise Edition - [Java EE javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/)), and you'll find a method named getCookies(). Follow the links, and you'll find how to extract the cookies you're interested in, and get their value.